# Did IBM make Watson Visual Recognition paid?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

It was originally free and I was using it for almost 3-4 months. It told me that I exceeded the quota so I deleted the project and created a new one. I went to Catalog then Watson Visual Recognition and the only plan avaialble is standard which means I have to pay but before I set it up for free and was using it fine since then. Am I doing something wrong or did IBM change something? I even tried this on a new account but it still says the same thing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per the Visual Recognition service release notes dated: 16-10-2020

Changes

The following new features and changes to the service are available.

16 October 2020

> You can no longer create a Lite plan instance of the Visual Recognition service. However,  existing Lite plan instances remain available. You can create new instances as billable Standard plans.

You can check the details in the [documentation here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/visual-recognition?topic=visual-recognition-release-notes#changelog)

Comment: Looks like it's going away completely now: "IBM will begin sunsetting Watson Visual Recognition on December 1, 2020. For a period of one year from this date, you will still be able to use Watson Visual Recognition. However, as of December 1, 2021 the offering will no longer be available."

Answer (score 0):

Yes,IBM has made visual recognition to paid..But lite version is still available on the cloud and you can use them for a while like 4-6 months and after the lite plan done you need to get a paid plan which gives you more abilities to do with IBM Watson services currently..And my suggestion if your trying to learn or want to learn or advance these topics see the docs of service.