# I can't choose lite plan in IBM Visual Recognition

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I am trying to provision IBM Visual Recognition, but cannot choose the lite plan. Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did IBM make Watson Visual Recognition paid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64417414/did-ibm-make-watson-visual-recognition-paid)

Answer (score 1):

See the [Release Notes for IBM Visual Recognition](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/visual-recognition?topic=visual-recognition-release-notes#changelog). There is news that the Lite plan is no longer available. Thus, it works as expected.